# RegExp with variable in a string format

Tags: javascript, regex

I created a RegExp that works as expected however I can't get it to work in a string format

```
var regex = new RegExp(/IN1\|2.*\r/g);
```

The regex is supposed to match the line number which will be taken from variable, in above example it would be line number 2. My question is how do I get it to a string format with a variable inside it?

I tried following but it just doesn't work: `"IN1\|" + lineNumber + ".*\x0d//g"`

Below is a text in case anyone wants to try:

```
IN1|**1**||QQ|Noth||||||||20190413|20190413||Self\r
IN1|**2**||QQ|Noth||||||||20190413|20190413||Self\r
IN1|**3**||QQ|LHS||||||||20200506|""||Private|||||||||||||||||||||2342344\r
```

Thank you.

Comment: Main point is that a backslash that forms a regex escape must be a literal backslash. `new RegExp("IN1\\|" + lineNumber + ".*\\r", "g")` or `new RegExp("IN1\\|" + lineNumber + ".*\r", "g")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahh, I don't know how I missed that, thank you!